Event Occurs After Navigating Back from Laravel Livewire Component Event
I've gone through the official documentation thoroughly, but I'm still unable to resolve this issue.
I'm currently using Laravel version 11 and Livewire version 3.
The problem is as follows:
When I dispatch an event from the right view page to the left view page and add a query string, navigating forward or backward in the browser triggers an unexpected /livewire/update event instead of normal page navigation. How can I resolve this?
{{--index.blade.php--}}
<div>
    <livewire:left wire:key="left"/>
    <livewire:right wire:key="right"/>
</div>

{{--right.blade.php--}}
<div>
    <a wire:click="$dispatch('emitCoinInfo', { market : 'KRW', coin : 'ETH'});"></a>
    <a wire:click="$dispatch('emitCoinInfo', { market : 'KRW', coin : 'BTC'});"></a>
</div>

//Left.php
namespace App\Livewire\Exchange;

use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Attributes\Renderless;
use Livewire\Attributes\Url;
use Livewire\Component;

class Left extends Component
{
    #[Url]
    public $code = 'KRW-EGX';
    public $coin = '';
    public $market = '';

    protected $queryString = ['code' => ['keep' => true]];
    
    #[On('emitCoinInfo')]
    #[Renderless]
    public function emitCoinInfo($market, $coin)
    {
        $this->code = $market . '-' . $coin;
        $this->market = $market;
        $this->coin = $coin;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('left');
    }
}

I'm forcibly reloading the page when navigating back because I haven't found a solution yet. However, this doesn't seem like a fundamental solution.
<script>
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function (event) {
        let pathName = window.location.pathname;
        if (pathName === '/exchange') {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
</script>

